# Expand textarea (and bring it to front) while it has the focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea, z-index

I want to expand a textarea (increase the height) as long as it has the focus. When expanded, the textarea should not move the content down, instead it should be displayed above the other content.

This is the code I'm using so far ([see here for an example](http://jsfiddle.net/NMGTp/)):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#txt1').focus(function () {
        $(this).height(90).css('zIndex', 30000);
        $('#txt2').val('focus');
    });
    $('#txt1').blur(function () {
        $(this).css('height', 'auto');
    });
});
```

The expanding of the textarea works fine, but I can't get it to display above the other elements on the page (it is displayed behind the elements which follow).

Are there any tricks to show the expanded textarea above/in front of all other elements?

**Update**: this is the (minmal) HTML code used to reproduce the problem:

```
<div style="height:20px;">first:<br/>
   <textarea id="txt1" rows="1" cols="20"
     style="width: 400px; height: 12px; font-size: 10px;">
   </textarea>
</div>
<br/>
second:
<br/>
<input type="text" id="txt2"/>
```

Comment: which is the CSS applied to the textArea and surrounding elements? This has to do with positioning.

Comment: There is no CSS (please click the link to see a running example)

Comment: Are you open to using a plug-in?  There's some really good ones out there that handle all of this.  Check this out: http://jsbin.com/ahaxe

Comment: @pixelbobby: does it support expanding the textarea vertically instead of horizontally?

Comment: Hey @M4N, yeah that one seems to be horizontal but the one I posted below does vertical.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting `position` on the `textarea` works. You can also get rid of the `z-index`.

[**Working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/NMGTp/25/)

Comment: @eykanal: My guess is that, as `z-index` only applies to positioned elements, the lack of position means that the elements are z-indexed in the order they appear on the page. Adding `position:relative` to one element brings it above the rest of the `static` elements, so that's why the `z-index` can be removed once `position: relative` is added.

Comment: @M4N: Ah well, I enjoyed being the accepted answer while it lasted :D

Comment: @Town: maybe I'll accept it again... later... please wait ;-)

Comment: @M4N: Please do, my privilege of proposing tag synonyms depends on it! ;)

Answer (score 4):

Adding a `z-index` does nothing without the element having a `position` other than static. Personally, I would add a class with all of the css changes and include an overlay, like this ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/NMGTp/26/)):

CSS

```
.focused {
    position: relative;
    height: 90px !important;
    z-index: 1000;
}
.overlay {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: #000;
    opacity: .75;
    filter: alpha(opacity=75);
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#txt1').focus(function () {
        $('<div class="overlay"/>').appendTo('body');
        $(this).addClass('focused');
        $('#txt2').val('focus');
    });
    $('#txt1').blur(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('focused');
        $('.overlay').remove();
        $('#txt2').val('blur');
    });
});
```

Comment: Nice solution, although the overlay would be distracting in my case.

Comment: That's fine :P, but I would still add the class with the height, because when the `#txt1` is blurred, it's `auto` height is taller than it was initially (as least for me in Firefox). Either that or save the original height as a number.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the style 'position:absolute;' on the first textarea (txt1) and that should do the trick.

Comment: Almost! Unfortunately this makes content located to the right of the textarea disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Try this plug-in.  Should be quick and simple: http://unwrongest.com/projects/elastic/

Answer (score 0):

working fiddle with `input` and `textarea`, mostly `css` with a little `jquery` for positioning

http://jsfiddle.net/Ap5Xc/